# Why can any Error be unconditionally converted to NSError?

Tags: swift, nserror

A lot of times, I'll receive a Swift `Error` object from a framework, which is really an `NSError`.

In order to access its information (e.g. `code`), I need to cast it to an `NSError`:

```
(error as NSError).code == ....
```

Why is this just an unconditional `as`? If I design my own error class that conforms to `Error`, it won't necessarily be an `NSError`, so how can this be the correct way to perform this cast?

Is there some kind of special case in the type system? This is a downcast that behaves like an upcast.

Answer (score 18):

I believe the capability for `Error` to be convertible to `NSError` is hardcoded into the compiler, and the actual bridging is implemented in the Swift runtime.

In [`runtime/ErrorObject.mm`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5696fb51af2b4af7a3064fc82051f516f156178a/stdlib/public/runtime/ErrorObject.mm), I found this comment:

```
// This implements the object representation of the standard Error
// type, which represents recoverable errors in the language. This
// implementation is designed to interoperate efficiently with Cocoa libraries
// by:
// - ...
// - allowing a native Swift error to lazily "become" an NSError when
//   passed into Cocoa, allowing for cheap Swift to Cocoa interop
```

And [this function](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5696fb51af2b4af7a3064fc82051f516f156178a/stdlib/public/runtime/ErrorObject.mm#L398-L461):

```
/// Take an Error box and turn it into a valid NSError instance.
id
swift::_swift_stdlib_bridgeErrorToNSError(SwiftError *errorObject) {
    ...

  // Otherwise, calculate the domain, code, and user info, and
  // initialize the NSError.
  auto value = SwiftError::getIndirectValue(&errorObject);
  auto type = errorObject->getType();
  auto witness = errorObject->getErrorConformance();

  NSString *domain = getErrorDomainNSString(value, type, witness);
  NSInteger code = getErrorCode(value, type, witness);
  NSDictionary *userInfo = getErrorUserInfoNSDictionary(value, type, witness);

  ...
}
```

The [ErrorHandling.rst document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/5696fb51af2b4af7a3064fc82051f516f156178a/docs/ErrorHandling.rst) says this about the rationale:

> It should be possible to turn an arbitrary Swift enum that conforms to `Error` into an `NSError` by using the qualified type name as the domain key, the enumerator as the error code, and turning the payload into user data.

(Parts of the document may be outdated.)

And [this is](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-4.2-branch/lib/AST/ASTContext.cpp#L4736-L4746) (I think) at least one part in the type checker were the information that `Error` is convertible to `NSError` is encoded (there are probably more):

```
  // Check whether the type is an existential that contains
  // Error. If so, it's bridged to NSError.
  if (type->isExistentialWithError()) {
    if (auto nsErrorDecl = getNSErrorDecl()) {
      // The corresponding value type is Error.
      if (bridgedValueType)
        *bridgedValueType = getErrorDecl()->getDeclaredInterfaceType();

      return nsErrorDecl->getDeclaredInterfaceType();
    }
  }
```

Comment: > the enumerator as the error code

An enum which doesn't confirm to a native type like Int, how is the enumerator determined? Is it guaranteed to be in order the cases are listed?

Answer (score 4):

This is a great question.

I thought I saw "An Error type can be bridged to an NSError" somewhere, but that must have been Xcode or some tutorial online.

Luckily I found this from [swift/NSError.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSError.swift).

```
// NSError and CFError conform to the standard Error protocol. Compiler
// magic allows this to be done as a "toll-free" conversion when an NSError
// or CFError is used as an Error existential.
extension NSError : Error {
  @nonobjc
  public var _domain: String { return domain }

  @nonobjc
  public var _code: Int { return code }

  @nonobjc
  public var _userInfo: AnyObject? { return userInfo as NSDictionary }

  /// The "embedded" NSError is itself.
  @nonobjc
  public func _getEmbeddedNSError() -> AnyObject? {
    return self
  }
}

extension CFError : Error {
  public var _domain: String {
    return CFErrorGetDomain(self) as String
  }

  public var _code: Int {
    return CFErrorGetCode(self)
  }

  public var _userInfo: AnyObject? {
    return CFErrorCopyUserInfo(self) as AnyObject
  }

  /// The "embedded" NSError is itself.
  public func _getEmbeddedNSError() -> AnyObject? {
    return self
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this! It still doesn't quite clear things up for me. It shows that both `NSError` and `CFError` implement `Error`, but it still doesn't show how I can take an arbitrary `Error` and make a 100%-safe cast to an `NSError` - it's like a downcast that behaves like an upcast. I guess the "compiler magic" part of the comment is where the solution lies.

Comment: True. There are other related sections, so hopefully that approximates to an answer :/

Comment: One other part of this that confuses me is that I can write a custom class that conforms to the `Error` protocol and I don't even need to provide the `localizedDescription` property in my class. Yet the class compiles and I can magically cast (using `as NSError`) my custom class to `NSError`. `Error` really seems to be a specially treated protocol.

Answer (score -4):

```
switch error {
case _ where (error as NSError).domain == self.domain:
   print("error from particular domain")
default:
   print("default error")
}
```